# Remove `-controller` prefix from spring-doc generated tags``

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, springdoc

Given a controller named `MyController`, spring doc generates the tag `my-controller` which in turn will generate a client `MyControllerApi`.

I'd like to remove this `-controller` suffix; is this possible with Spring-Doc?

Answer (score 1):

This component will automatically remove any `-controller` suffix on tags

```java
@Component
public class RemoveControllerTagSuffix implements OpenApiCustomiser {
    @Override
    public void customise(OpenAPI openApi) {
        openApi.getPaths()
               .forEach((s, pathItem) ->
                       pathItem.readOperations()
                               .forEach(operation ->
                                       operation.setTags(operation.getTags()
                                                                  .stream()
                                                                  .map(t -> t.replace("-controller", ""))
                                                                  .toList())));
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach helped me to add examples to generated endpoints. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Use the @Tag annotation, and set the tag up manually with the name and description you want.

```
@RequestMapping("/myendpoint")
@Tag(
    name= "My Name",
    description = "What my controller does"
)
public class MyController {

}
```

You can also specify tag grouping on individual methods using the @Operation annotation and defining the tags property.